# 'Lottie/Lottie.h' file not found XCODE 12.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, cocoapods, pods

Desde que he actualizado a XCODE 12, no me importa el framework de Lottie y me dice que no encuentra el framework Lottie a la hora de compilar. Con el mimso código y mismos PODS, en XCODE 11 si me compila.

Mi proyecto está en objetive C y tengo la versión ---> pod 'lottie-ios', '<= 2.1.5'

[image: lottie error]

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente en Xcode:

1. Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations y en Derived Data haces click en la flecha para que se abra el directorio y eliminas el contenido.
2. Product -> Clean builder.

En el direction en donde tienes el archivo `Podfile` elimina el archivo `Podfile.lock` y la carpeta `Pods`. Luego ejecuta el comando desde la terminal:

```
pod update
```

Adicional a eso puedes utilizar la última versión de Lottie para Objective-C y compilar el proyecto nuevamente.

```
pod 'lottie-ios', '~>2.5.3'
```